# Add element to array then encode it to json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this code

```
$data['events'] = $this->calendar_model->get_events();
    foreach ($data['events'] as $arr) {
        settype($arr,"array");
        $arr['something'] = false;
         //print_r($arr);
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

what I am trying to do is to add something => false to each record of the array
so lets say I got from the database
array of

```
title:"aaaaa",
start: "xxxx",
end: "cccc",
```

I want to add to each one something :false to become like

```
    title:"aaaaa",
    start: "xxxx",
    end: "cccc",
    something,false
```

for each record

but the problem is when I print using the `print_r` its fine, but the `json_encode` print only the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Passing by value vs. by reference

You are passing your `$arr` by value in your `foreach` loop. Try to pass it by reference.

This is done by adding a `&` just before your `$arr` variable in your loop declaration:

```
foreach ($data['events'] as &$arr) {
    settype($arr,"array");
    $arr['something'] = false;
}

echo json_encode($data['events']);
```

### How it works

**Passing by value** means that your foreach loop instanciates a **local copy** or your array. All modifications made inside the loop will affect only the local copy.

**Passing by reference** means that inside your loop, you are working **directly on the original array**. But be careful when doing that because it can be dangerous. For instance, I don't know what are the consequences of calling `setType($arr,"array");` for the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're not collecting `$arr` from each iteration of your loop into anything. It looks like you probably want to push `$arr` onto another array that stores everything, and then JSON encode that new array.

Try this:

```
$collection = array();
$data['events'] = $this->calendar_model->get_events();
foreach ($data['events'] as $arr) {
    settype($arr,"array");
    $arr['something'] = false;
    array_push($collection, $arr);
}
echo json_encode($collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['events'] = $this->calendar_model->get_events();
foreach ($data['events'] as &$arr) {
    settype($arr,"array");//This if there is not array
    $arr['something'] = false;
}
echo json_encode($data['events']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to make your own json like this

```
$strJson = '';
$data['events'] = $this->calendar_model->get_events();
foreach ($data['events'] as $arr) {
    settype($arr,"array");
    $arr['something'] = false;
     //Assign value as yours in blow code
    $strJson .= '{"title" : "'.$arr.'","start" : "'.$arr.'","end" : "'.$arr.'"},';        
}

$strJson1=rtrim($strJson, ",");
$newStr = '['.$strJson1.']';
echo $newStr;
```